# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm having a crash with high occurrence. I didn't find any trace of it. Somehow, I managed to know that after recreating an activity I fill recyclerView with my static list. Here's the crash coming from.

```
Choreographer.java line 911

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:817)
   at android.animation.AnimatorSet$DependencyListener.startIfReady(AnimatorSet.java:799)
   at android.animation.AnimatorSet$DependencyListener.onAnimationEnd(AnimatorSet.java:753)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1239)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.cancel(ValueAnimator.java:1140)
   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:820)
   at android.animation.AnimatorSet$DependencyListener.startIfReady(AnimatorSet.java:799)
   at android.animation.AnimatorSet$DependencyListener.onAnimationEnd(AnimatorSet.java:753)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1239)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.cancel(ValueAnimator.java:1140)
   at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:974)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.animationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1384)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:1427)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:759)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler$1.run(ValueAnimator.java:801)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

In my `onViewCreated`, I just call this method

```
private fun initRecyclerView() {
    val list = ArrayList<HomeFeature>()
    list.add(HomeFeature(id = 0, iconId = R.drawable.ic_home_collage, imageId = R.drawable.ic_home_bg_collage, title = globalActivity.resources.getString(R.string.home_title_1)))
    list.add(HomeFeature(id = 2, iconId = R.drawable.ic_home_edit, imageId = R.drawable.ic_home_bg_camera, title = globalActivity.resources.getString(R.string.home_title_3)))
    list.add(HomeFeature(id = 1, iconId = R.drawable.ic_home_camera, imageId = R.drawable.ic_home_bg_edit, title = globalActivity.resources.getString(R.string.home_title_2)))
    list.add(HomeFeature(id = 3, iconId = R.drawable.ic_home_filters, imageId = R.drawable.ic_home_bg_filters, title = globalActivity.resources.getString(R.string.home_title_4)))
    list.add(HomeFeature(id = 5, iconId = R.drawable.ic_home_settings, imageId = R.drawable.ic_home_bg_settings, title = globalActivity.resources.getString(R.string.home_title_6)))
    list.add(HomeFeature(id = 4, iconId = R.drawable.ic_home_saved, imageId = R.drawable.ic_home_bg_saved, title = globalActivity.resources.getString(R.string.home_title_5)))
    binding.incItemCollageHome.item = list[0]
    binding.incItemEditHome.item = list[1]
    binding.incItemCollageHome.itemClick = itemClick
    binding.incItemEditHome.itemClick = itemClick

    val adapter = AdapterHome(itemClick)
    binding.rvFeaturesHome.adapter = adapter
    val subList = list.subList(2, 6)
    adapter.submitList(subList)
}
```

Adapter Class (DiffUtil), I'm using data binding along my list_item. So, overything is handled.

```
class AdapterHome(private val onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener) : ListAdapter<HomeFeature, AdapterHome.ViewHolderHome>(diffUtilHome) {

    companion object {
        val diffUtilHome = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<HomeFeature>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: HomeFeature, newItem: HomeFeature): Boolean {
                return oldItem.id == newItem.id
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: HomeFeature, newItem: HomeFeature): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolderHome(val binding: ListItemHomeBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolderHome {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ListItemHomeBinding>(layoutInflater, R.layout.list_item_home, parent, false)
        return ViewHolderHome(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolderHome, position: Int) {
        val homeFeature = getItem(position)
        holder.binding.apply {
            item = homeFeature
            itemClick = onItemClickListener
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is `Choreographer.java line 911`?

Comment: Can you post the Adapter class? This code looks good to me

Comment: It's not my class, it's android built-in class from `android.view.Choreographer`

Comment: I'm fetching the same error. Did you get the solution?

Comment: before this fragment, I was recreating the activity, So, I changed the methodology..